# jQuery UI 1.9 tooltip on button not working on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, checkbox, tooltip

i'm using jQuery UI 1.9 to make buttons of checkboxes and for tooltips.  My HTML is simple:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="jq-ui-button" value="Test" title="tooltipppp">
<label for="jq-ui-button">Label ok</label>
```

Then i call in JS:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").button();
$("input[type='checkbox']").tooltip();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/JnApC/

The problem is that i see the tooltip when i click the button/checkbox but i want to see the tooltip normally on hover. Is this a bug in jQuery UI 1.9 or how can i achieve the effect i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that when `.button()` is applied to a checkbox, it is the associated label that is styled to be the button. It may therefore be necessary to apply the `.tooltip()` to the label rather than to the checkbox itself:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").button();
$("label[for='jq-ui-button']").tooltip();
```

The associated `title` attribute would therefore also need to be applied to the label instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="jq-ui-button" value="Test">
<label for="jq-ui-button" title="tooltipppp">Label ok</label>
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. The `title` attribute should also be relocated to the `<label>` element. Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JnApC/1/). Also note you can apply tooltips globally by calling `$(document).tooltip()` once instead of `$("selector").tooltip()` for several selectors.